# How to disable release upgrade notification at terminal/TTY login (not the GUI pop-up)?

Tags: command-line, upgrade, notification, motd

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on one of my old laptop. Each time I login through TTY or SSH it says:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.4.0-030400-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

New release '14.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

However, this system cannot be upgraded because this machine is too old to support PAE, and I don't want to upgrade it either. Could you please tell me how to hide this notification (the last two lines) at terminal login? It doens't seem to be related to the shell I use.

I found a lot of questions about disabling the GUI Update Manager pop-ups, but didn't find anything helpful to the terminal notification.

Comment: The same settings control the GUI and the CLI for updating releases.

Comment: @muru Those settings don't hide the hint for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That output is part of the [MOTD](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/update-motd.5). To disable it, remove the execute permissions for `/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available`.

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available
```

The output maybe cached for a while, it may take a few login attempts for the message to clear out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I need. Actually it worked immediately for me.

Comment: Also had to chmod -x  /etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade

Comment: I was wondering for a whole now: what do I have to read to know such things? In the old days I used to read the 'Secrets' book series by IDG Press about the registry and DOS. I am looking for an 'under the hood' guide specifically for Ubuntu and  Linux in general...

Answer (score 17):

Do this:

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade
```

This only removes the message about a release upgrade. It keeps the message about package updates, including security updates, which I would like to keep getting.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Change the `Prompt=` line from `Prompt=lts` to `Prompt=never`.

OR

```bash
sudo sed -i 's/Prompt=.*/Prompt=never/' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Comment: There is already an accepted answer for this question. How is yours an improvement?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the config of update manager is to be the better option as answered by user *rise worlds*, as you're configuring the behavior of the daemon itself.

```
sudo sed -i 's/Prompt=.*/Prompt=never/' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

This is clearly spelled out in

```
cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

The future ou will not run into problems tracking down the changing-between-releases file names in /etc/update-motd.d/, and you can even easily change the behavior to check for LTS and non-LTS versions of Ubuntu. If you really want to get heavy-handed on the upgrade check, remove execute:

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd
```