# Software Updater Partial Upgrade

Tags: 18.04, update-manager

Ubunbtu 18.04
I started getting the notice that not all updates can be installed - which led me to the following post:
[Software Updater partial upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719221/software-updater-partial-upgrade)
I ran the two commands mentioned - sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Then re-booted, and re-ran software updater, and got the same notice
I ran the 2 commands again, and nothing was installed, but I still get the same notice when using software updater.

[image]

If I click on continue, I see this:

[image]

Can anyone shed any light on this?  How can I prevent seeing the partial upgrade notice?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1096015/1206611

Comment: From the post I mentioned, it is the wording that is confusing - the "partial upgrade" does not refer to an OS upgrade, but it refers to package upgrades.

Comment: Open a terminal. Run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`. If there are any errors, post the entire output of both in your question above. Don't edit or summarize -- we need to see the detail.

Comment: I ran sudo apt update and then sudo apt upgrade.  No errors, but when I ran sudo apt upgrade, I did get a list of packages that were no longer required suggesting I run sudo apt autoremove.  After runnuing autoremove and re-booting, I no longer see the partial upgrade notice when running software updater.
If you still think it would be helpful to others, I can paste the results of sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade

Comment: Whatever the problem was, seems like you solved it. Congratulations.